# How to Bypass Model Validation Based Upon Object Attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, attributes, conditional-statements

If `someday` boolean is equal to `true` than how to skip validations?

**challenge.rb**

```
validates :name, :categorization, :category, presence: true, :unless => (:someday == true)
```

**challenges_controller**

```
def create
  if params[:challenge][:someday] == "1" # I had to use "1" instead of "true" for this conditional to work
    # saves challenges
  else
    # brings to create.html.erb and then saves
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by passing a validate: false to your save method. Like this

```
def create
  if params[:challenge][:someday] == "1" # I had to use "1" instead of "true" for this conditional to work
    @item = item.new(item_params)
    @item.save(validate: false)
  else
    # brings to create.html.erb
  end
end
```

One more thing to note, it you're using `1` inside quotes, that's a string, and won't be considered as a boolean, unless you get it as a string in your params. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `:unless =>` a symbol (representing a method to call), a string (of valid Ruby code to execute), a Proc to call, or an Array containing more than one of these.

So, your validation line would be:

```
validates :name, :categorization, :category, presence: true, unless: { |challenge| challenge.someday }
```

See "Conditional Validation" here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless

Comment: I went with Kumar because I like how `(validate: false)` is more concise. Thank you though for your insight :)